# Functionality of files created on Publishing the VB.net application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What are all the files will be created when we publish the vb.net application
and functionality of each files

Comment: Using what publish technology?  ClickOnce, MSI, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699352.aspx

> For any ClickOnce publication, the chain of dependencies includes the
>   following:
>
> A deployment manifest that points to itself or to another deployment
>   manifest through the embedded deployment provider URL. (ClickOnce
>   supports a one-hop redirect through this URL.) A deployment manifest
>   that points to the application manifest through an embedded code base
>   URL. An application manifest that contains relative paths to each of
>   the application files. These files must reside in the same folder or a
>   subfolder in which the application manifest resides. The application
>   files themselves, usually with a .deploy file name extension appended
>   to the file name to simplify mapping these files to MIME types on the
>   deployment server. ClickOnce automatically strips off the .deploy file
>   name extension on the client side after the file is downloaded.